# -ing forms of verb. Gerund or participle? Adverb or Adjective?

Tags: adverbs, participles

I try to figure out these "-ing" forms in the following examples. They appears to be participles but not used as adjectives, and more like adverbs (complementing the action of the verbs).

1. She came in running.
2. I feel good paying high rent.
3. I went back walking.
4. She crossed the garden dancing.
5. I came down the stairs jumping.

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think #2 is not the same as the other sentences.  In the other sentences, the "-ing" word is describing the verb, but in #2 "paying" is the verb.

Comment: You are right: they are all verb participles functioning as adjuncts (adverbials).

Comment: I know it may sound unnatural. But if these sentences are rephrased, these participles may act like adjectives. "I came down the stairs jumping" --> "Jumping up and down, I came down the stairs." However, in the original sentences, these participles act like adverbs. It's quite confusing for me.

Comment: Compare "She came in **running** (verb) and "She came in **tired**. (adjective). Some participles do have adjective forms, for example "the **entertaining** clown" / "The movie was very **frightening**".